# ASP.NET Core WebAPI Security Considerations

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My WebAPI is, just that, an API backend for my UI to consume. In fact, I will have perhaps 10's of WebAPI services that my UI will use.

I'm having difficulty understanding what I need to consider in terms of security.

My APIs are secured using Bearer tokens, and allow https only. I have CORS set up and they only allow the origin `https://my-front.end` This all works great.

However.. how can I protect against C/XSRF and replay attacks on a WebAPI? Do I even need to?

Setting up anti-CSRF is rather painless with an ASP.NET MVC project, but how can you do it on a WebAPI one, from what I understand it relies on sending information, generated on the server, to the client to send along in the body of the request and through another channel (e.g. cookie or header). I read that you can protect against replay attacks by using a nonce (e.g. timestamp and random number) -- some how -- but can't find any implementation examples.

Is there anything else I need to consider?

---

Edit: front end uses vue.js, but we have a very competent JS programmer so any front-end implementations won't be a problem. It's just a matter of finding out *what* needs to be done!

May also be worth noting, for sake of obviousness, WebAPIs and FrontEnd run on different servers, so these are all, effectively, cross origin calls.

Comment: Are you using something like Angular on the front end? Can you add this to your question because Angular has defaults setup for CSRF tokens etc.

Comment: No, it's vue.js, I've edited the question appropriately. @MindingData

Comment: OK one sec. Just working it out for you :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK so. First up, you will need to be sending the XSRF token in a header. To do this you need to go to your ConfigureServices method and setup the AntiForgery service to expect this header.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAntiforgery(x => x.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Next you need to generate the token. Because the front end and API are different services, you will need to work out when you do this. You could do it when you login for example, or you could have a dedicated endpoint doing this but the end result is the same.

You can either return the token value in a header or cookie it's up to you. In my example I've used a Cookie which I'll explain later but you can use a header if you like.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiForgeryService;

    public HomeController(IAntiforgery antiForgeryService)
    {
        _antiForgeryService = antiForgeryService;
    }

    public IActionResult GetToken()
    {
        var token = _antiForgeryService.GetTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken;
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", token, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
        return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
    }
}
```

The IAntiforgery service should already be able to be used (It's part of the "AddMVC" call you will be using already in .net core services).

OK, so now we have returned a cookie with a token value. Now we just need to be able to send it back.

Here is some jQuery doing the legwork

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.4/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var token = Cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "X-XSRF-TOKEN": token
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now something to note is that AngularJS automatically does this. When $http is used, it goes and looks for a cookie named "XSRF-TOKEN", and it will then send it as a header automatically. Because you are using Vue you will basically be doing this anyway but a bit more of a manual process.

Also important to note, DO NOT set this up to expect the cookie back as the CSRF token. Otherwise you've defeated the entire purpose of CSRF anyway.

Then you can go ahead and decorate your actions/controllers with the AntiForgery attribute.

```
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

In conclusion what it basically boils down to :

- Setup .net Core AntiForgery to expect a header value to use for the CSRF token
- Have an endpoint that will manually generate a token for you to use and return it as a cookie/header
- Have your front end read this value and store it for subsequent requests
- On subsequent requests send the token value as a header (Not a cookie)

Mostly taken from here : http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/05/18/csrf-tokens-angularjsjquery-asp-net-core/

Comment: Brilliant thanks so much! I shall have a go with this in the coming days. I need to read up about how CSRF attacks are done to better understand this, the part which I find weird is manually requesting the token instead of having it baked in to the form by the server. I'm probably best reading up before asking inane questions :)

Comment: Well actually, baked in the form is the normal way if you aren't using a SPA (http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/05/17/csrf-tokens-asp-net-core/). But you need to be using the Razor HTML helpers when building the form. You "could" still put it as a hidden field on the form but it doesn't make sense if you are using a SPA anyway.

Comment: Yeah makes sense! If all my endpoints are protected using bearer auth (oidc), do I need to worry about this? Token is appended to request in our js application - so if a user is sent to a dodgy site that tries to call `our.api/protected/endpoint` it just won't do anything because auth token won't be appended?

Comment: That would be correct. CSRF is based on what a browser "stores" and sends with every request. e.g. A cookie is sent with every single request to that site.

Comment: Just a heads up, while the above tutorial is great, one thing that let me down was getting the XSRF token and saving it as a cookie. Instead of using _antiForgeryService.GetTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken; it's better to use _antiForgeryService.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext) instead as this also returns & automatically creates and stores the AspNet.AntiForgeryToken cookie that you will need to avoid getting 400 returned all the time even when you are putting your XSRF token correctly in the header of your requests.

Comment: It's the `XSRF` open to anyone?  For example Let's say I'm an attacker and when you visit my page with your auth cookie I call `GetToken()`. That will give me a `XSRF` token. Can't I then go ahead and make requests? The attacker shouldn't be able to generate `XSRF` tokens.